# google-apps-script: standalone with prompt box

Tags: google-apps-script

My purpose is to code the most basic google-apps-script (standalone) which uses a "prompt box" to acquire a sheet name from the user. Next, the script will update the sheet. I already have tested the update and it works correctly.  However, I'm unclear about the most current method to code the standalone so it can correctly use the prompt box?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please study the [Apps Script documentation for Serving HTML](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/)  If you have general questions, you can join the [Apps Script community](https://plus.google.com/communities/102471985047225101769)  Stack Overflow is not for general support questions for Google.  Always provide your existing code for a good question.  Include troubleshooting output, error messages, and explain expected and current results.

Answer (score 0):

This is off the top of my head so it may not be 100% correct.

```
var response = SpreadsheetApp.getUi().prompt('Title','Prompt string', buttons)
var t = response.getResponseText();
```

It's a lot easier to do in the code editor because it prompts you with the correct choices as long a the code up to that point is correct. You can always go to help and select api and go to spreadsheets and select SpreadsheetApp and read about the getUi() and the Ui itself.  Just try their examples and you will writing these things on your own in no time.